# When a theme is updated , all the theme folder files are updated or just specific files?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a child theme from a theme I have , I added some files/folders to the theme folder and get them using `get_template_directory()` , `get_templete_directory_uri()`.

-Will these files/folders be removed when the theme is updated ?
-If so , Is there is a better way to add new files/folders to the child theme?

Comment: For more on Child Themes: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: it depends on theme develepers. if they changed the folder hiearchy( don't think so ), then it'll broken. but your child theme will stay same

Answer (score 0):

yes it will remove for that you have to create child theme or create plugin so it will be there even after update theme